# iOS - Scrolling Images from plist data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I have created a gallery with `UICollectionView` , and load a set of images from a plist file , when user touches each cell , a fullscreen image will be loaded (same as iPhone's Photos application) , so I have faced with a problem which is when photo will be fullscreen I can not scroll and view other images , here is my codes :

then in PhotosViewerController :

```
-(void) creatContentWithNumerOfPage: (NSInteger) numberOfPage andCurrentPage: (NSInteger) currentPage andImageArray:(NSArray *)imageArray {

    self.pageControl.numberOfPages = numberOfPage;
    self.pageControl.currentPage = currentPage;
    [pageScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width * pageControl.numberOfPages, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    pageScrollView.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview: pageScrollView];


    NSMutableArray *mArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:thumbnailViewController.imageArray.count];
    for (int i = 0; i <= thumbnailViewController.imageArray.count; i++)
    {

        NSDictionary *picturesDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Photos" ofType:@"plist"]];
        imageArray = [picturesDictionary objectForKey:@"PhotosArray"];

        fullScreen = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[imageArray objectAtIndex:currentPage]]];
        [fullScreen setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
        fullScreen.frame = self.view.frame;

        [mArray addObject:fullScreen];
        [pageScrollView addSubview:fullScreen];
    }

}
```

EDITED : (solution)

```
-(void) creatContentWithImages:(NSArray*)imageArray andCurrentPage:(NSInteger)currentPage{

    self.pageControl.numberOfPages = imageArray.count;
    self.pageControl.currentPage = currentPage;
    [self.pageScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.pageScrollView.frame.size.width * imageArray.count, self.pageScrollView.frame.size.height)];


    for (int i = 0; i < imageArray.count; i++)
    {


        NSDictionary *picturesDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Photos" ofType:@"plist"]];
        imageArray = [picturesDictionary objectForKey:@"PhotosArray"];

        fullScreen = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[imageArray objectAtIndex:i]]];


        [fullScreen setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
        fullScreen.frame = CGRectMake(i*self.pageScrollView.frame.size.width, 0, self.pageScrollView.frame.size.width, self.pageScrollView.frame.size.height);

        [self.pageScrollView addSubview:fullScreen];
    }

    [self scrollToPage:currentPage animated:NO];

}
```

Comment: I was looking at your reputation and I was wondering how on Earth you had 4 gold and 15 silver badges with 3 rep... And then I understood.

Comment: @H2CO3 so what was that ?!!

Comment: you had 500 but the bounty took it all :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code have a lot of issues, for example

- you call `creatContentWithImages` **before** `viewDidLoad` method and at this
  point we can't expect real values of `self.view.frame` or
  `self.pageScrollView.frame`, you have to call it in/after `viewDidLoad`.
  Maybe like this:

  ```
  [self presentViewController:photosViewController animated:YES completion:^{
      [photoViewController creatContentWithImages:images andCurrentPage:row];
  }];
  ```
- in cycle you always use `currentPage` instead of `i` ivar
- you send `imageArray` into `creatContentWithNumerOfPage` method but
  for some reason this array is being overriden here with new data (I
  suppose with the same data)
- it's also unclear why you perform `[self.view addSubview:

  pageScrollView]` - is UIScrollView created programmatically? But in which place it happens?
- when you operate with frames then you should use UIScrollView frame, 
  not UIView, if your scroll size will be different from UIView then
  design will be broken as well.

I've changed it and improved some things, so let look at this (I posted all whole PhotosViewerController.m file)

```
#import "PhotosViewerController.h"
@implementation PhotosViewerController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void) creatContentWithImages:(NSArray*)imageArray andCurrentPage:(NSInteger)currentPage{
// I create UIScrollView programmatically, if you want to use xib then just remove lines with RM comment. 
// There are two views in xib hierarchy - UIScrollView downward and UIPageView above

    self.pageScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame]; //RM
    self.pageScrollView.pagingEnabled = YES; //RM

    self.pageControl.numberOfPages = imageArray.count;
    self.pageControl.currentPage = currentPage;
    [self.pageScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.pageScrollView.frame.size.width * imageArray.count, self.pageScrollView.frame.size.height)];

    self.pageScrollView.delegate = self;//RM
    [self.view insertSubview:self.pageScrollView atIndex:0]; //RM

    for (int i = 0; i < imageArray.count; i++) //not <=, just <
    {
        UIImage *img = [imageArray objectAtIndex:i];// not sure whether imageArray contains UIImage's or NSString, so if here NSString the create UIImage in appropriate manner. I've tested it with UIImage's 
        UIImageView *fullScreen = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];
        [fullScreen setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
        fullScreen.frame = CGRectMake(i*self.pageScrollView.frame.size.width, 0, self.pageScrollView.frame.size.width, self.pageScrollView.frame.size.height);

        [self.pageScrollView addSubview:fullScreen];
    }

    [self scrollToPage:currentPage animated:NO]; // scroll to corresponding page
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll: (UIScrollView *) sView
{
    CGFloat offset = self.pageScrollView.contentOffset.x;
    CGFloat pageSize = self.pageScrollView.frame.size.width;

    int page = floor((offset + (pageSize/2)) / pageSize);
    self.pageControl.currentPage = page;
}

- (IBAction)changeThePage:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Change");
    [self scrollToPage:self.pageControl.currentPage animated:YES];
}

- (void)scrollToPage:(NSInteger)page animated:(BOOL)animated{
    CGRect pageRect = CGRectMake(page * self.pageScrollView.frame.size.width, 0, self.pageScrollView.frame.size.width, self.pageScrollView.frame.size.height);    
    [self.pageScrollView scrollRectToVisible: pageRect animated: animated];

    [self.pageControl setCurrentPage:page];
}
@end
```

If you still have any questions then let me know, and I try help you.

Comment: Thankks !!!! but I little bit change your code :D check out my edited code , now works FINE !